# Как поправить css для вложенного элемента?

Tags: css3, css

Есть div.postcontent.

1. В нем могут быть просто ссылки: `div.postcontent p a`
2. Ссылки могут содержать картинку: `div.postcontent p a img`

Есть навороченный css для ссылок. Мне нужно его отключить для ссылок, содержащих картинки. Т.е. для варианта (1), он должен работать, для (2) не работать.

```
.postcontent a:before{
    content: "\25BA";
    font-size: 80%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 3px;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: На днях уловил где-то мысль, что сейчас думают о вводе такого родительского селектора в CSS, который помог бы вам. Сейчас, лично мне, на вскидку приходит два решения: перепродумывать HTML: т.е. вешать класс .no-effects на ссылки-картинки, или наоборот. Либо, если нет такой возможности, писать простенький JS/JQuery скрипт, который пробежит по всем ссылкам и расклассифицирует их добвлением того же амого .no-effects

Comment: Ок принято, я думал есть какой то вариант через css и я его не знаю. Повешу через jquery. Этот вариант в моем случае надежней, чем предложенные ниже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Интересный случай...Что-то решения я не вижу.
Попробуй вот-так

```
.postcontent a{position:relative}
.postcontent a img:before{position:absolute;//ваш код}
```

Ты ведь сможешь отпозиционировать относительно A.

Comment: Буду делать через jquery, но вариант интересный, спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй:

```
< img ... onload="this.parentNode.className +=' myOverrideClass'"/>
```

Хотя у [[@koza4ok](/users/8972/koza4ok)](/users/8972/koza4ok) лучше.